How can you reference non-selected columns within across()?
I have a dataframe with integer columns x1, x2, x3, ... and bool columns x1_status, x2_status, x3_status, ...
df = tibble(
    x1 = 1:5,
    x1_status = c(T, T, T, F, F),
    x2 = 6:10,
    x2_status = c(F, T, T, T, F),
    x3 = 11:15,
    x3_status = c(F, F, T, T, T)
)

How do I calculate the mean of x1, x2, x3, ... at the values where x1_status is True, x2_status is True, x3_status is True, and so on, respectively? I'd like to use across() within summarize() so I don't have to list each x column individually.
That is, I'm hoping to get a dataframe with columns mean_x1 = 2, mean_x2 = 8, and mean_x3 = 14.
I was thinking of something like
df |>
    summarize(
        across(
            !matches("_"),
            \(value_col) {
                status_col = str_c(cur_column(), "_status")
                mean(value_col[.data[[status_col]]])
            },
            .names = "mean_{col}"
        )
    )

but that doesn't work. I'd also like to avoid using df[[status_col]], so I can include this in a pipeline that might create the x1, x2, x3, ... columns without having to assign df in the interim.

Welcome to SO! Try with get instead of with the .data pronoun, i.e. use mean(value_col[get(status_col)]). See e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349087/refer-to-column-name-from-variable-in-across-in-dplyr (altough in this question .data works too (; )

Using pivot_longer() might be more intuitive:
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  x1 = 1:5,
  x1_status = c(T, T, T, F, F),
  x2 = 6:10,
  x2_status = c(F, T, T, T, F),
  x3 = 11:15,
  x3_status = c(F, F, T, T, T)
)

# Pivot to longer dataset
df_long <- df %>%
  rename_with(
    ~ paste0(., "_value"),
    c(x1, x2, x3)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_sep = "_",
    names_to = c("name", ".value")
  )

# Summarize
long_summary <- df_long %>%
  filter(status) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value))

# Pivot to wide summary
wide_summary <- long_summary %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "name",
    values_from = "value",
    names_prefix = "mean_"
  )

print(wide_summary)


Another approach is to NA out the x*es that have an FALSE status and use na.rm when applying the mean.
Like the following
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  x1 = 1:5,
  x1_status = c(T, T, T, F, F),
  x2 = 6:10,
  x2_status = c(F, T, T, T, F),
  x3 = 11:15,
  x3_status = c(F, F, T, T, T)
)

df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("_"), ~ ifelse(.x, T, NA))) %>%
  reframe(across(!matches("_"), .names = '{col}_mean') * pick(matches("_"))) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   x1_mean x2_mean x3_mean
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1       2       8      14

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
